# Redirect category to another

Tags: php, magento

I have a product category which contains a number of sub categories. I would like when you click on the parent category to redirect into one of the child categories. Additionally my client would like to change which category it redirects into periodically, so the configuration of this needs to be controlled through the Magento admin too.

Wondering if it would be possible to accomplish this through the 'Custom Layout Update' field?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with Catalog -> URL Rewrite Management

1. Open the current 'System' entry for the redirecting category under this page
2. Grab the ID Path and Request Path for this entry
3. Delete this entry
4. Go back to the URL Rewrite Management screen
5. Add URL Rewrite
6. Select 'Custom' from the drop-down menu
7. Fill in the ID Path and Request Path from step 2
8. Fill in the Target Path with the target page's Target Path (which you can get from its own URL Rewrite entry)

This really isn't a good idea; I'd personally use an Apache rewrite or something, but this way it's manageable from the Admin panel. Your client will only need to do step 8 after you do the setup.

Comment: As @bkconrad said, I would really not use URL Rewrite Management for this. This is going to cause issues when you try to refresh indexes (this isn't tested, but Magento will try to create missing System indexes, and will fail if yours has the same ID)

Comment: I have confirmed that reindexing the database will overwrite these custom URL rewrites, so this is not a valid solution.